# How to validate internal consistency of a config with dhall?

Tags: dhall

I will start with a motivating example of a config that almost represents an envoy proxy config :)

```
virtual_hosts:
- name: webxp-api_http
  domains: ["*"]
  routes:
  - match: { prefix: "/static/v5.0" }
    route: { cluster: bodhi_static }
  - match: { prefix: "/"}
    route: { cluster: bodhi-web }

  clusters:
  - name: bodhi_web
  - name: bodhi_static
```

The rule is, that name has to be defined `clusters` list have to be defined to be used in the `route` part of the config. If you look closely, this config will fail to load, because `bodhi_web` is not `bodhi-web`. How would I encode that in Dhall?

On one hand I could have `clusters` as a list in a let binding, and that would help, but nothig forces me to use the binding and in reality I would like tho think of `clusters` as a sum-type for the `cluster:` field? Could dependent types help me here (i.e. I remember doing something like this in purescript, that has some limited capacity for dependent type-programming)

Or should I just create a constructor/validator function and abuse assert to get this validated?

Or I just shouldn't? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by authoring a utility function that generates a correct-by-construction configuration.

Using your example, if we want to ensure that the list underneath the `clusters` field always matches the list of routes, then we derive the `clusters` field from the `routes` field:

```
let Prelude = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/package.dhall

let Route = { match : { prefix : Text }, route : { cluster : Text } }

let toVirtualHosts =
          \(args : { name : Text, domains : List Text, routes : List Route })
      ->  { virtual_hosts =
                  args
              //  { clusters =
                      Prelude.List.map
                        Route
                        Text
                        (\(r : Route) -> r.route.cluster)
                        args.routes
                  }
          }

in  toVirtualHosts
      { name = "webxp-api_http"
      , domains = [ "*" ]
      , routes =
          [ { match = { prefix = "/static/v5.0" }
            , route = { cluster = "bodhi_static" }
            }
          , { match = { prefix = "/" }
            , route = { cluster = "bodhi_web" }
            }
          ]
      }
```

```
$ dhall-to-yaml --file ./example.dhall
virtual_hosts:
  clusters:
  - bodhi_static
  - bodhi_web
  domains:
  - *
  name: webxp-api_http
  routes:
  - match:
      prefix: /static/v5.0
    route:
      cluster: bodhi_static
  - match:
      prefix: /
    route:
      cluster: bodhi_web
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to define `clusters` manually, then require that any value used in a route already appear in `clusters`? Presumably, there may be more than one route that uses the same cluster, and this approach would just generate a "bloated" list of clusters if you mistype a cluster name in a route.

Comment: On one hand, in reality the clusters' definition will contain much more than just a name. On the other, with Dhall, I don't really care if I am re-defining cluster over-again in Dhall, because `let ... in ..` clause can save me there :) ... will try to play with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

My alternative attempt, heavily relying on the fact, that empty alternatives will end-up being text when converted to yaml, i.e: `{cluster = <static |  web>.static}` is interpreted as `cluster: static`

This means, I can i.e:

```
let Clusters = < bodhi_static | bodhi_web >

let Route =
      { Type = { match : { prefix : Text }, cluster : Clusters }
      , default = {=}
      }

let Cluster = { Type = { name : Clusters }, default = {=} }

in  { matches =
        [ Route::{ match = { prefix = "/" }, cluster = Clusters.bodhi_web }
        , Route::{
          , match = { prefix = "/static" }
          , cluster = Clusters.bodhi_static
          }
        ]
    , clusters =
        [ Cluster::{ name = Clusters.bodhi_static }
        , Cluster::{ name = Clusters.bodhi_web }
        ]
    }
```

Bit more repetitive, but simpler i.m.o?